# XAMPP is not updating .html/.js files on reload

Tags: html, xampp, localhost

I recently installed XAMPP on a windows machine(Windows 10) just to get a local server up and running so that I could make API calls and not run into any CORS issues and it was working fine.
Now what is happening is that whenever I make any changes in the .html or .js files it won't update the page, I have cleared all the browser history , temp files, restarted XAMPP, closed and reopened the browser (in the root folder there is only a single .html file so no clash there) but still it won't update.

Is it something related to XAMPP(v3.2.2) or any local settings that I have to configure.

Browser: Chrome 65, though it is the same issue with firefox and IE.

Comment: try to echo out the time, see if it change to determine whether it serves old pages.

Comment: I am using it mostly for web development not primarily related to PHP, I know there are other ways to set up local servers, but this seems more stable and feature rich.

Comment: yes, but you have to find out when the page got cached or how long will it last.

Answer (score 2):

It can be due to serve caches. You need to clear those caches. Go to browsing history and clear there or you can just right click on the reload button on chrome and click hard reload and cache clear.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me I usually do (if you're using Mac) SHIFT + Cmd + R and if that doesn't work i close the tab (Chrome) and open a new one.